# Mocking MailController with ActionMailer.net using Moq

Tags: tdd, moq, actionmailer.net

I'm trying to mock my `MailController`

```
_mockMailController = new Mock<IMailController>();
_mockMailController.Setup(x => x.ForgotPassword("test@email.com"));
```

My controller takes an `IMailController` as a dependancy, however when I call

```
mailController.ForgotPassword("test@email.com").Deliver();
```

I get a NullReferenceException (because `ForgotPassword` doesn't return anything, I guess)

Ideally, we'd stub `EmailResult` ?

Comment: How did you implement ForgotPassword method in your controller?

Comment: It's not a 'Controller' as such. I followed this: http://geeksharp.com/2011/01/26/actionmailer-net-email-templates-for-the-mvc-crowd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a pull request for the ActionMailer.Net that intoduces an IEmailResult interface that makes mocking very easy. Have a look at this:

https://bitbucket.org/swaj/actionmailer.net/pull-request/4/iemailresult-interface-for-better/

Until the pull request is merged you could use a custom build from my frok of the project.

https://bitbucket.org/hydr/xv-actionmailer.net

Mocking get's as easy as writing (with FakeItEasy, Moq might be similar):

```
//SetUp
_myMailer = A.Fake<IMyMailer>();

//Later on in Assert
A.CallTo(() => _myMailer.MyTestEmail()).MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
```

when the Mailer is defined like:

```
public class MailController : MailerBase, IMyMailer
{
    public IEmailResult MyTestEmail()
    {
        To.Add("recipient@sdf.com");
        From = "sender@sdf.com";
        Subject = "Subject";
        return Email();
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate any reviews on my pull request btw :)

Answer (score 1):

You have not created a setup for the mock return a value from ForgotPassword method. With default behavior this will return default value for the type, which is null in this case.

You can mock the return value like this:

```
_mockMailController.Setup(x => x.ForgotPassword("test@email.com"))
                   .Returns(new SomeType());
```

Comment: Yes, I realise this. I'm sorry, perhaps i should have been more specific in my question. The return type for this is a very complex (and itself has lots of dependencies) so i was looking for someone who'd used ActionMailer.net, and mocked it, to share their experience

Comment: Well if you are not going to do anything with the the return type, you could move ActionMailer.Net code to another class. This way you could skip testing and mocking 3rd party component code.